# Convert SQL query with a one-to-many relationship to an ASP.NET Core / Entity Framework Core call with a parent/children object structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

You can see my db table structure here on SqlFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/05fce/12/0

I have this SQL query that returns a list of products (webspiderproduct table) and for each product it lists the lowest price from each shop (webspiderproductprice table). Here is the query:

```
select 
    t1.ProductId,
    t1.productname,
    t2.shopId,
    t2.price as lowestPrice
from 
    webspiderproduct t1
join 
    (select 
         *,
         row_number() over (partition by webspiderproductid, shopid 
                            order by price asc) as rn 
     from webspiderproductprice) t2 on t1.productid = t2.webspiderproductid
where 
    rn = 1
order by 
    ProductId
```

I am now trying to convert this query so that it can be called through ASP.NET Core using Entity Framework Core. The problem is that I would rather that it returns its data like this:

```
 ProductId: 1, ProductName: "sample product1"
   shopId: 1, lowestPrice: 100
   shopId: 2, lowestPrice: 199
 ProductId: 2, ProductName: "sample product 2"
   shopId: 1, lowestPrice: 99
   shopId: 2, lowestPrice: 119
   shopId: 3, lowestPrice: 19
```

So that it can easily be looped through in the view using an outer foreach product loop and then an inner loop called for each product.lowestShopPrices loop.

But then the query should be structured so that it returns a list of products where each contain a list of shopids/shopprices.

How would you change the SQL query so that it returns the data using the Entity Framework Core and in a parent/children structure instead?

Comment: Use group by. It does what you need. Just make sure you construct the key object with the data you need.

Comment: LINQ query.based on model, so what you have tried and which model do you have?

Comment: Could you please add the description of the tables that you query.

Comment: Hi Rob - I am unsure what you mean by "use group by". Givko: I have added a link to the db table structure at the top of my description.

Comment: Just post classes that you have, we especially interested in your navigation properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your classses looks like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPrice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

You can write EF query:

```
var result = ctx.Products
            .Join(ctx.Prices
                    .GroupBy(n => new { n.ProductId, n.ShopId })
                    .Select(n => new{ n.Key.ProductId, n.Key.ShopId, MinPrice = n.Min(m => m.Price) }),
                p => p.Id, pp => pp.ProductId, (p, pp) => new { p.Id, p.Name, pp.ShopId, pp.MinPrice })
            .OrderBy(n => n.Id)
            .ToList();
```

which will produce exactly the result you need.

[image]

Comment: hi @Posio - Thanks for the solution - it is perfect. When I come to think of it I want to only return the newest price (column dateFound) from each - how would you do that ? thanks in advance

Comment: @NickDeveloper newest price by what ? By product and shop or maybe only by product ?

Comment: If you want to group by Shop and Product so you'll get newest price for every product in every shop, then you can simply change GroupBy Select delegate: 

.Select(n => new { n.Key.ProductId, n.Key.ShopId, 
                            Date = n.Max(m => m.DateFound), 
                            Price = n.Where(m => m.DateFound == n.Max(o => o.DateFound)).Select(m => m.Price).First() })

Unfortunately it's a little tricky because EF Core don't support OrderBy in JOIN / Group. Also, make sure to use EF Core version > 6.0

Comment: the newest Price by shop - so that for each product it will show multiple rows of shops with the latest price found for each of them - using the dateFound column in the ProductPrice table.

Comment: Thanks - So should I remove the GroupBy ? what would you add after .Join(context.WebSpiderProductPrices

Comment: ctx.Products.Join(ctx.Prices.GroupBy(n => new { n.ProductId, n.ShopId })
                      
                        .Select(n => new { n.Key.ProductId, n.Key.ShopId, 
                            Date = n.Max(m => m.DateFound), 
                            Price = n.Where(m => m.DateFound == n.Max(o => o.DateFound)).Select(m => m.Price).First() })
                    ,
                    p => p.Id, 
                    pp => pp.ProductId, (p, pp) => new { p.Id, p.Name, pp.ShopId, pp.Date, pp.Price })
                .OrderBy(n => n.Id)